# Is calling member functions without object instantiation undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, inheritance, member-functions

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class BaseNode {
    public:
        BaseNode(std::string s) {
            std::cout << "Called BaseNode(string)" << std::endl;
        }
        BaseNode() {
            std::cout << "Called BaseNode()" << std::endl;
        }

        void count(int num) {
            std::cout << "count() in BaseNode " << num << std::endl;
        }

};

class MyNode : public BaseNode {
    public:
        MyNode() : BaseNode("test") {
            std::cout << "Called MyNode()" << std::endl;
        }

        void count(int num) {
            std::cout << "count() in MyNode " << num << std::endl;
        }

};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    MyNode *mn;
    mn->count(6);
    return 0;
}
```

To my surprise this compiles and prints "count() in MyNode 6". But *should* it work?

If I declare count as virtual in the base class

```
class BaseNode {
    public:
        BaseNode(std::string s) {
            std::cout << "Called BaseNode(string)" << std::endl;
        }
        BaseNode() {
            std::cout << "Called BaseNode()" << std::endl;
        }

        virtual void count(int num) {
            std::cout << "count() in BaseNode " << num << std::endl;
        }

};
```

I get "Segmentation Faul" on the count call. What is going on behind the scenes here?

Comment: No, this invokes *undefined behavior* - which means anything can happen (including seemingly working correctly)

Comment: it is undefined. Actually the member function isnt that relevant, already with `mn->` all bets are off. It appears to work, because the method isnt actually using `this`

Comment: Build with `-Wall` and the compiler will answer your question: https://godbolt.org/z/v1xqMe `<source>: In function 'int main(int, char**)': <source>:33:14: warning: 'mn' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]  mn->count(6);`

Comment: A method which doesn't use `this` can be made `static` and called without a member (but class scope). However, `static` methods may not be `virtual`. (The `virtual` does in fact an access to `this` to pick-up the virtual method table of the resp. object.)

Comment: In `main()`, `mn` is an uninitialised pointer, so even *accessing its value* (such as when comparing it with `nullptr`) gives undefined behaviour.   Dereferencing a pointer (for example, using it to call a non-static member function) requires accessing the value of  the pointer.    One of the joys of undefined behaviour is that it is perfectly feasible for the result to be "whatever you think works".

Comment: "Undefined behavior" does not mean "something bad will happen". It means only that the language definition does not tell you what your program will do.

Answer (score 3):

`MyNode *mn;` creates a [Wild Pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer#Cause_of_wild_pointers), or a Dangling Pointer--that is, one that points to memory you don't own. So trying to dereference the pointer and fetch that memory is indeed Undefined Behavior.

> What is going on behind the scenes here?

Since this is Undefined Behavior, *we don't know.* The results here are determined by whatever your compiler decided to do, which could very well include [making "demons fly out of your nose."](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)